# An unexisting variable in print() in Python.PY code

Tags: python, compiler-errors, discord.py

So, I tried to create a discord bot and I wrote this code:

```
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break

    print(
        f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
        f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})'
    )

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Then VSCode shown me this:

```
    f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'guild' referenced before assignment
```

Idk where it found "guild" variable, please help me removing this error!

Comment: VScode may fail to show the error, as it's one string that is splitted on 2 lines, but that comes from the `guild` just after. If the `client.guilds` is empty, you have no `guild` defined

Comment: I think that this is because you want to get `guild` outside of the for loop try to put the `print()` function in the `if guild.name==GUILD` before `break` and put both strings into one string. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that, guild *may* not be defined. For example:

This works:

```py
for my_var in [0, 1]:
    pass

print(my_var)
```

This gives a NameError, because my_var is never defined.

```py
for my_var in []:
    pass

print(my_var)
```

You need to set a default value for guild (you can do this by putting `guild=None` above your for-loop) or by putting the print statement inside the for-loop.

Answer (score -2):

It was little big for comment.

I have changed your code a litte. As eror is unknown. This code will at least help  you to identify error
import os

```
import discord
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(client.guilds) # try to print number of child of client.guilds. I think they are Zero
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break # This break does not gurantee guild is initalized
    # safety check to make code showing proper error
    if guild is not None:
        print(dir(guild))
        print(
            f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
            f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})'
        )

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: You removed the import of os which will cause a new error and also, the issue appears to be one that guild is not defined because the guild should be populated by a loop through the client.guilds

Comment: what is client.guilds is empty but iterable ?

Comment: `''.join(f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})\n' for guild in client.guilds)` this will just be empty if there are no guilds. And you just add it to the first part of the string.

Comment: The client.guilds is server list, i guess?

Comment: This doesn't solve the actuall problem. If guild is undefined, you can check `if guild is not None`